# Linking two Threads in a Client-Server Socket program - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server, mutex

I create threads of class **A** and each sends a serialized object to a **Server** using ObjectOutputStream.

The **Server** creates new Threads **B** for each socket connection (whenever a new **A** client connects)

**B** will call a synchronized method on a Shared Resource **Mutex** which causes it (B) to **wait()** until some internal condition in the Mutex is true.

In this case how **A** can know that **B** is currently waiting?

Hope this description is clear.

Class Arrangement:

```
A1--------->B1-------->|       |
A2--------->B2-------->| Mutex |
A3--------->B3-------->|       |
```

**EDIT:**
it's a must to have wait(), notify() or notifyAll(), since this is for an academic project where concurrency is tested.

Comment: Why does A need to know? Will B block for an extended amount of time? If so, the approach probably will not scale at all...

Comment: Why needs A to know that B is waiting?

Comment: What does A need to know that B is currently waiting? After sending the serialized object does A not wait for B to send a response back?

Comment: A is a GUI. each serialized object sent over socket is added to a queue in Mutex. So, when this queue becomes full, B will have to wait till it frees some slots in the queue. So the end user has to see a message like "Please wait while a slot becomes free" :) . User will have to wait for a reply from B (when it becomes notified by Mutex) in order to continue operations...

Comment: Just always show a message (Waiting) and remove it if process is finished (will be fast if B doesn't have to wait).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally A would read on the socket, which would "block" (i.e. not return, hang up) until some data was sent back by B. It doesn't need to be written to deal with the waiting status of B. It just reads and that inherently involves waiting for something to read.

**Update** So you want A's user interface to stay responsive. By far the best way to do that is take advantage of the user interface library's event queue system. All GUI frameworks have a central event loop that dispatches events to handlers (button click, mouse move, timer, etc.) There is usually a way for a background thread to post something to that event queue so that it will be executed on the main UI thread. The details will depend on the framework you're using.

For example, in Swing, a background thread can do this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(someRunnableObject);
```

So suppose you define this interface:

```
public interface ServerReplyHandler {
    void handleReply(Object reply);
}
```

Then make a nice API for your GUI code to use when it wants to submit a request to the server:

```
public class Communications {

    public static void callServer(Object inputs, ServerReplyHandler handler);

}
```

So your client code can call the server like this:

```
showWaitMessage();

Communications.callServer(myInputs, new ServerReplyHandler() {
    public void handleReply(Object myOutputs) {

        hideWaitMessage();
        // do something with myOutputs...

    }
});
```

To implement the above API, you'd have a thread-safe queue of request objects, which store the `inputs` object and the handler for each request. And a background thread which just does nothing but pull requests from the queue, send the serialised inputs to the server, read back the reply and deserialise it, and then do this:

```
final ServerReplyHandler currentHandler = ...
final Object currentReply = ...

SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        currentHandler.handleReply(currentReply);

    }
});
```

So as soon as the background thread has read back the reply, it passes it back into the main UI thread via a callback.

This is exactly how browsers do asynchronous communication from JS code. If you're familiar with jQuery, the above `Communications.callServer` method is the same pattern as:

```
showWaitMessage();

$.get('http://...', function(reply) {

    hideWaitMessage();

    // do something with 'reply' 
});
```

The only difference in this case is that you are writing the whole communication stack by hand.

**Update 2**

You asked:

> You mean I can pass "new ObjectOutputStream().writeObject(obj)" as
>   "myInputs" in Communications.callServer?

If all information is passed as serialised objects, you can build the serialisation into `callServer`. The calling code just passes some object that supports serialisation. The implementation of `callServer` would serialise that object into a `byte[]` and post that to the work queue. The background thread would pop it from the queue and send the bytes to the server.

Note that this avoids serialising the object on the background thread. The advantage of this is that all background thread activity is separated from the UI code. The UI code can be completely unaware that you're using threads for communication.

Re: `wait` and `notify`, etc. You don't need to write your own code to use those. Use one of the standard implementations of the [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface. In this case you could use `LinkedBlockingQueue` with the default constructor so it can accept an unlimited number of items. That means that submitting to the queue will always happen without blocking. So:

```
private static class Request {
    public byte[] send;
    public ServerReplyHandler handler;
};

private BlockingQueue<Request> requestQueue;

public static callServer(Object inputs, ServerReplyHandler handler) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream).writeObject(inputs);

    Request r = new Request();
    r.send = byteStream.toByteArray();
    r.handler = handler;
    requestQueue.put(r);
}
```

Meanwhile the background worker thread is doing this:

```
for (;;) {
    Request r = requestQueue.take();

    if (r == shutdown) {
        break;
    }

    // connect to server, send r.send bytes to it
    // read back the response as a byte array:

    byte[] response = ...

    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            currentHandler.handleReply(
                new ObjectInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(response)
                ).readObject()
            );
        }
    });
}
```

The `shutdown` variable is just:

```
private static Request shutdown = new Request();
```

i.e. it's a dummy request used as a special signal. This allows you to have another public static method to allow the UI to ask the background thread to quit (would presumably clear the queue before putting `shutdown` on it).

Note the essentials of the pattern: UI objects are never accessed on the background thread. They are only manipulated from the UI thread. There is a clear separation of ownership. Data is passed between threads as byte arrays.

You could start multiple workers if you wanted to support more than one request happening simultaneously.

Comment: +1 for the instant reply. Pls have a look at my above comment.

Comment: I would have given another +1. Will take sometime to read this up and tell if this solves the issue.. I want the A which is linked with the waiting B, to prevent user to do anything on that GUI. I also tried EDT stuff before, you can see my previous posts are all about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696472/background-process-in-swingworker-causes-eventqueue-to-freeze-in-java-complete-c

Comment: how will the method "handleReply" and class "ServerReplyHandler" look like?

Comment: Where I say "So your client code can call the server like this:" immediately below that is an example where I implement `ServerReplyHandler` and the `handleReply` method. It is an interface (not a class), and you implement it differently depending on how you want to handle the reply. A convenient way (as in my example) is to implement it "on the spot" with an anonymous class.

Comment: Thanks. Any tip on how to adapt this to Sockets? You mean I can pass  "new ObjectOutputStream().writeObject(obj)" as "myInputs" in Communications.callServer?

Comment: It's a must to use wait(), notify(), notifyAll() in my case. where to include those?

Comment: They should be hidden inside a blocking queue class. Here's a fine one:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: hi, thanks a **lot** for the edit. In my case, it's a **must** to have wait(), notify() or notifyAll(), since this is for an academic project where concurrency is tested. appreciate if you can insert the relevant methods as well. sorry for bothering this much.